# Make chat box in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a chat box for my website and it should be fixed at the bottom right position of page. When someone clicks on it that it should slide up and details are visible in it.
I am using html,css,jquery.
Suggest help from these only.

Comment: What code you achieved?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. I am doing it now and side by side i have asked thos question so that if i can't able to get what i want than i can get solution from here and my time is not wasted.

Comment: I get it, if someone does the work for you, then your time is never wasted... I suggest you first try on your own, and then post here what you have, and people here will try to correct your approach.

Comment: Ok thanks i will first try on my own and see what i can do.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service or a *"how to"* tutorial service and there are lots of tutorials and scripts on the web for this.

Comment: This question is not easy googleable with words used by OP, also the given answers seems dated - like this one for example
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986357/live-chat-software-for-websites

Answer (score 5):

You can look at examples of socket.io for chat.
https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Desing:
https://codepen.io/oktaykose/pen/aypyvg

```css
.chat-box{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.box{
    transition: height 1s ease-out;
    width: 300px;
    height: 0px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.open:hover>.box{
  height:400px;
      transition: height 1s ease-out;
}
.open {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #3F51B5;
    background: #673AB7;
    color: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-box">
  <div class="open">Open
  <div class="box">
    <br>
    Test
    <br>
  </div>
    <div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the sample as per your requirement.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
 .LiveChat{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0%;
 height:10%;
 background-color:red;
 }
 </style>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
    $("#chatBtn").click(function()
    {
        $(".LiveChat").css("height","30%");
    });
 });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="LiveChat">
<button id="chatBtn">Live chat</button>
<p>rest of details below</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please mark it as answer if its matching your need.**